# Integrating Selenium Webdriver tests written in Java to SpiraTest

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium2, browser-automation

I'm interested in *[SpiraTest](https://www.inflectra.com/SpiraTest/)'s* and *Selenium Webdriver's* collaboration. My objective - launch a Selenium test written in *Java* on *Eclipse*. Can the SpiraTest quality management tool **run** .exe or .bat files and then get the outcome of them to **show test results**? I've found some information about *Spira RemoteLaunch* plug-in, however, the amount of information is meagre and misleading. Any help?

Comment: In the past I used both SpiraTest and later SpiraTeam. I found their support to be very good, so at the very least I'd give them a call and ask: https://www.inflectra.com/Support/External.aspx. I know at some point they created a separate tool called Rapise for WebDriver integration, perhaps this will help: https://www.inflectra.com/Rapise/Highlights/Selenium-WebDriver-Integration.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

SpiraTest is a quality management tool that allows you to plan, track, and report on your testing efforts. It can be used to manage manual and automated testing, including tests written using Selenium WebDriver.

To integrate Selenium tests written in Java with SpiraTest, you will need to use the SpiraTest RemoteLaunch plugin. This plugin allows you to execute test cases from within SpiraTest by launching a command-line application on your local machine. You can use this plugin to launch a .bat or .exe file that runs your Selenium tests.

To use the RemoteLaunch plugin, you will need to:

Install the plugin on your local machine.
Configure the plugin to point to the location of the .bat or .exe file that you want to launch.
In SpiraTest, create a new test case and select the "RemoteLaunch" test type.
Enter the command-line arguments that you want to pass to the .bat or .exe file when it is launched.
Run the test case from within SpiraTest.
The RemoteLaunch plugin will execute the .bat or .exe file on your local machine and pass it the specified command-line arguments. The output of the .bat or .exe file will be captured and displayed in the test case results in SpiraTest.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate Selenium Webdriver tests written in Java with SpiraTest, you will need to utilize the SpiraTest RemoteLaunch plug-in. This plug-in allows you to execute test cases stored in SpiraTest, using a remote execution engine such as Selenium Webdriver. You can then report the test results back to SpiraTest, so that they can be tracked and analyzed.

Here are the general steps to follow:

1. Install the SpiraTest RemoteLaunch plug-in in your Eclipse environment.
2. Create test cases in SpiraTest that correspond to your Selenium tests.
3. Create a batch file or shell script that will execute your Selenium tests using the appropriate command line arguments.
4. In SpiraTest, set the test case execution type to "Remote" and provide the path to your batch file or shell script.
5. Execute the test cases from within SpiraTest and monitor the results.

It is important to note that the specifics of this integration will depend on the specifics of your SpiraTest installation and your Selenium tests. You may need to modify the batch file or shell script as needed to properly execute your tests and return the results to SpiraTest.